# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize

Tags: installation, deserialization, binaryformatter

I borrowed a Program using BinaryFormatter serialization.
An important task for me was to change it in XML serialization.
I developed a converter program which reads the via BinaryFormatter serialized file and saves it in XML.
The program works fine when it's laying in its own project and is executed by hand, but when I call it via the Visual Studio Installer Project it breaks with a SerializationException with the message "The Assembly XXX can not be found".

Why does it work when I execute it manually and automated I get this exception?
Can anybody give me a hint how to solve this issue?

Greets
Henrik

Comment: Assembly reference is missing, Make sure that the all reference are added in the installer?

Comment: The project is the same as it runs for its own. The method is renamed from Main() to Install(ByVal savedState As IDictionary) but nothing else changed.